# Why the picture is black?

Tags: java

Write a method Picture emboss to add an emboss style effect to a picture by applying the following kernel.

```
| -2 -1  0 |
| -1  1  1 |
|  0  1  2 |
```

(it is a 3*3 matrix)

When applying a kernel filter to a pixel near the boundary, some of its neighboring pixels may not exist. In such cases, assume the leftmost column wraps around to the rightmost column, and vice versa; and the top row wraps around to the bottom row, and vice versa.

Below is part of my code, but I find that the picture I get is all black. I only have a limited knowledge of java. So after checking for some time, I still can not find the error.

```
public static Picture emboss(Picture picture) {
        int width= picture.width();
        int height= picture.height();

        int[][] matrix1 = new int[height][width];
        int[][] matrix2 = new int[height][width];
        int[][] matrix3 = new int[height][width];

        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < height; row++){
                Color color = picture.getColor(col, row);
                matrix1[row][col] = color.getRed();
                matrix2[row][col] = color.getGreen();
                matrix3[row][col] = color.getBlue();
                
                int a = row-1;
                int b = col-1;
                int c = row+1;
                int d = col+1;

                if (a < 0) {
                    a = height-1;
                }
                if (b < 0) {
                    b = width-1;
                }
                if (c > height-1) {
                    c = 0;
                }
                if ( d > width-1 ) {
                    d = 0;
                }

                int GR = -2 * matrix1[a][b] - matrix1[row][b] - matrix1[a][col] + matrix1[row][col] + matrix1[c][col] + matrix1[row][d] + 2*matrix1[c][d];
                int GG = -2 * matrix2[a][b] - matrix2[row][b] - matrix2[a][col] + matrix2[row][col] + matrix2[c][col] + matrix2[row][d] + 2*matrix2[c][d];
                int GB = -2 * matrix3[a][b] - matrix3[row][b] - matrix3[a][col] + matrix3[row][col] + matrix3[c][col] + matrix3[row][d] + 2*matrix3[c][d];

                if (GR < 0) {
                    GR=0;
                }
                if( GR>255 ) {
                    GR=255;
                }
                if ( GG<0 ) {
                    GG=0;
                }
                if( GG>255 ) {
                    GG=255;
                }
                if ( GB<0 ) {
                    GB=0;
                }
                if ( GB>255 ) {
                    GB=255;
                }

                Color newColor= new Color(GR,GG,GB);
                picture.setColor(col,row,newColor);
            }
        }
        return picture;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a matrix like this

`int[][] matrix1 = new int[height][width];`

It is by default filled with 0s.

Look at when you actually give the matrix a value. in the first iteration of the for loops, everything is black. You start by setting the current pixel:

`matrix1[row][col] = color.getRed();`

But all the neighbours are still black. When you move in the iterations, all pixels that have not been computed yet are black and you include them in the computation when you use the neighbours.

You should start by an iteration just to fill these three matrices, followed by another iteration for the computation:

```
for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++){
        Color color = picture.getColor(col, row);
        matrix1[row][col] = color.getRed();
        matrix2[row][col] = color.getGreen();
        matrix3[row][col] = color.getBlue();
    }
}

for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++){
        int a = row-1;
        int b = col-1;
        [...] // The rest of the code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: That's right. I should start by an iteration to add pixel values to all these matrices, and then use another iteration to compute. Thank you for your help!